# Javascript/HTML5 fillStyle won't change

Tags: javascript, html

I've got all my Javascript code working except this part.
The problem is that it does not change color even though it prints the 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 alerts. Any ideas on what i may be doing wrong?

- It is always the default black square.
- Assume that tile is a random float.
- waterline is equal to 50.
- tile_size is 4.

  ```
          var tile = Math.round(this.map[y][x]);
          if(tile <= this.waterline) {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(25, 25, tile+75)";
              alert("1");
          }
          else if(tile > this.waterline && tile <= this.waterline + 10) {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(tile+80, tile+80, 100)";
              alert("2");
          }
          else if(tile > this.waterline + 10 && tile <= this.waterline + 40) {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255-tile, 0)";
              alert("3");
          }
          else if(tile > this.waterline + 40 && tile <= 190) {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255-tile, 0)";
              alert("4");
          }
          else if(tile > 190) {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255-tile, 255-tile, 255-tile)";
              alert("5");
          }
          alert(ctx.fillStyle + "   " + tile + "   " + this.waterline);
          ctx.fillRect(x * this.tile_size, y * this.tile_size, this.tile_size, this.tile_size);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, strings are not parsed.  You need to correctly escape your `tile` variables:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+(255-tile)+", "+(255-tile)+", "+(255-tile)+")";
```

Comment: Without more code, I can't really create a test case to be sure.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I already realized that before you even posted the comment.